# React, the problem is in displaying data on the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

The data is received correctly, the array is filled with data, it includes an object inside which an array with objects. You can see it calmly in the console, but There are no images displayed on the screen:(

By the way, in the console, initially this array is null, but only after the data is loaded. Maybe the page rendering happens before the data arrives

Here is my component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import "../../../index.scss"
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import {OneCollection} from "../../../http/getImages.js";

const ImagePage = () => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
    const {id} = useParams()

    useEffect(() => {
        OneCollection(id).then(data => setImage(data))
    }, [])

    console.log(image, "Нужный массив")

    return (
        <div>
            <p>WORKING</p>
            <div>
                {image?.info?.length > 0 ? (
                    image.info.map((imageId) => (
                        <div key={imageId}>
                            {imageId.title}
                        </div>
                    ))
                ) : (
                    <div>There are no Images :(</div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ImagePage;
```

How can I fix the problem in displaying data on the page?

I tried to write this way, but the only difference is how the array will be visible in the console, but it is not displayed on the screen

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import "../../../index.scss"
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import {OneCollection} from "../../../http/getImages.js";

const ImagePage = () => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState({info: []})
    const {id} = useParams()
    useEffect(() => {
        OneCollection(id).then(data => setImage(data))
    }, [id, setImage, image]) // добавляем image в зависимости

    console.log(image, "Нужный массив")
    return (
        <div>
            <p>WORKING</p>
            <div>
                {
                    image.info && image.info.length ? image.info.map(imageId =>
                        <div key={imageId}>
                            {imageId.title}
                        </div>
                    ) : <div>There are no Images :(</div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ImagePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that the `OneCollection function` is **asynchronous** and returns a Promise. The component uses `setImage` to set the value of image to the result of OneCollection. However, when the component first renders, `image is null`, so trying to access properties of image like `image.info.length` or `image.info.map()` will cause an error.

You should add a check to make sure image is not null before accessing its properties. You can also use a loading state to show a loading message until the image data is fetched.

```
const ImagePage = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    OneCollection(id)
      .then((data) => setImage(data))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, [id]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>WORKING</p>
      <div>
        {image && image.info && image.info.length > 0 ? (
          image.info.map((imageId) => (
            <div key={imageId}>
              {imageId.title}
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
          <div>There are no Images :(</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```